# sign in with firebase ios email

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in

I am trying to implement firebase sign in with apple but I have several issues.
Firebase provided a code for cryptographical to implement ios sign in, but I don't anything about cryptographical.

I copied all the code without any modification from: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple

And I have several issues:

```
authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
```

## - Cannot assign value of type 'SignInOut' to type 'ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding?'

What is this type? how do I assign it? (SignInOut - is the name of my class)

and the second issue:

```
let hashedData = SHA256.hash(data: inputData)
```

## - Use of unresolved identifier 'SHA256'

What is this identifier? what should I do with it?

third, sign in with apple is available only for ios 13 and above. how can I make sure that other devices can use my app without signing in with apple?
If I implement this feature all my signing class won't be available for other versions

Am I implementing it the right way? should I just copy all the code and go on? do I need to add anything in addition? (except all my app features)

Answer (score 2):

## Use of unresolved identifier 'SHA256'

Firebase forgot to document that you need to import CryptoKit.

So just add `import CryptoKit` to the top of your file.

## - Cannot assign value of type 'SignInOut' to type 'ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding?'

I don't have an answer for this yet. But if you add your code then I can update my answer.

I'm also working on building a sample project which uses SwiftUI to implement signing in with Apple to a Firebase project. I don't know when it will be done, but maybe it will help out in the future. https://github.com/joehinkle11/Login-with-Apple-Firebase-SwiftUI